# How to use and "in" clause in "having" in HIVE?

Tags: sql, sqlite, hadoop, hive

I have my data in sometable like this:

```
col1    col2    col3   
A       B       3
A       B       1
A       B       2
C       B       1
```

And I want to get all of the unique groups of `col1` and `col2` that contain certain rows of col3.  Like, all groups of col1 and col2 that contain a "2".

I wanted to do something like this:

```
select col1, col2 from sometable 
group by col1, col2
having col3=1 and col3=2
```

But I want it to only return groups that have an instance of both 1 and 2 in col3.  so, the result after the query should return this:

```
   col1    col2
   A       B
```

How do I express this in HIVE?  THANK YOU.

Comment: What would happen if more than one element in col1 meets the criteria in col3, how would you write that.  As in if C also had a 2 element in col3, would the answer be `[A,C]` (an array) for col1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why others deleted answers that where correct and then almost correct but I will put their's back up.

```
SELECT col1, col2, COUNT(DISTINCT col3)
FROM
    sometable
WHERE
    col3 IN (1,2)
GROUP BY col1, col2
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT col3) > 1
```

If you actually want to return all of the records that meet your criteria you need to do a sub select and join back to the main table to get them.

```
SELECT s.*
FROM
    sometable s
    INNER JOIN (
       SELECT col1, col2, COUNT(DISTINCT col3)
       FROM
          sometable
       WHERE
          col3 IN (1,2)
       GROUP BY col1, col2
       HAVING
          COUNT(DISTINCT col3) > 1
    ) t
    ON s.Col1 = t.Col1
    AND s.Col2 = t.Col2
    AND s.col3 IN (1,2)
```

The gist of this is narrow/filter your rowset to the rows that you want to test col3 IN (1,2) then count the `DISTINCT` values of col3 to make sure both 1 and 2 exist and not just 1 & 1 or 2 & 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think below mentioned query will be useful for your question.

```
select col1,col2
from Abc
group by col1,col2
having count(col1) >1 AND COUNT(COL2)>2
```